# Bootstrap4 Multi-Step Form not responsive

Tags: javascript, html

I use boostrap4 and angular 7

I use multi step form.
I have a problem when I display in mobile device , it's not responsive

this a screen in desktop

[image]

this a screen in mobile

[image]

I want that the step depend on screen size.

this is the code :

html

```
<!-- MultiStep Form -->
<div class="container-fluid" id="grad1">


    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-0">

        <div class=" card-header">
            <h2 class="title float-left" style="color:cadetblue;">
              <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" ></i>
              Save Request
            </h2>


          </div>

        <div class="col-11 col-sm-9 col-md-7 col-lg-12 text-center p-0 mt-3 mb-2">
            <div class="card px-0 pt-4 pb-0 mt-3 mb-3">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 mx-0">
                        <form id="msform">
                            <!-- progressbar -->
                            <ul id="progressbar">
                                <li class="active" id="step1"><strong>1</strong></li>
                                <li id="step2"><strong>2</strong></li>
                                <li id="step3"><strong>3</strong></li>
                                <li id="step4"><strong>4</strong></li>
                                <li id="step5"><strong>5</strong></li>
                                <li id="step6"><strong>6</strong></li>
                                <li id="step7"><strong>7</strong></li>
                                <li id="step8"><strong>8</strong></li>
                                <li id="step9"><strong>9</strong></li>
                                <li id="step10"><strong>10</strong></li>

                            </ul> <!-- fieldsets -->
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-card">
                                    <h2 class="fs-title">Test step1</h2> 

                                    <div class=" form-group">
                                      <label>test: </label>
                                      <input class=" form-control"
                                             name="secondname"
                                             placeholder="" required
                                             type="text">
                                    </div>

                                    <div >
                                      <label>Last NAME: </label>
                                      <input 
                                             name="secondname"
                                             placeholder="" required
                                             type="text">
                                    </div>

                                  </div>
                                   <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn-info float-right" value="next" />



                              </fieldset>


                    <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-card">
                                    <h2 class="fs-title">Test step2</h2> 

                                    <div class=" form-group">
                                      <label>Adr: </label>
                                      <input class=" form-control"
                                             name="secondname"
                                             placeholder="" required
                                             type="text">
                                    </div>

                                    <div >
                                      <label>Phone: </label>
                                      <input 
                                             name="secondname"
                                             placeholder="" required
                                             type="text">
                                    </div>

                                  </div>
                                  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn-info float-right" value="next" />



                              </fieldset>

                 <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-card">
                                    <h2 class="fs-title">Test step3</h2> 

                                    <div class=" form-group">
                                      <label>test: </label>
                                      <input class=" form-control"
                                             name="secondname"
                                             placeholder="" required
                                             type="text">
                                    </div>



                                  </div>
                                  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn-info float-right" value="next" />



                              </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-card">
                                    <h2 class="fs-title">Test step4</h2> 

                                    <div class=" form-group">
                                      <label>test: </label>
                                      <input class=" form-control"
                                             name="secondname"
                                             placeholder="" required
                                             type="text">
                                    </div>



                                  </div>
                                  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn-info float-right" value="next" />



                              </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-card">
                                    <h2 class="fs-title">Test step5</h2> 

                                    <div class=" form-group">
                                      <label>test: </label>
                                      <input class=" form-control"
                                             name="secondname"
                                             placeholder="" required
                                             type="text">
                                    </div>



                                  </div>
                                  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn-info float-right" value="next" />



                              </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-card">
                                    <h2 class="fs-title">Test step6</h2> 

                                    <div class=" form-group">
                                      <label>test: </label>
                                      <input class=" form-control"
                                             name="secondname"
                                             placeholder="" required
                                             type="text">
                                    </div>



                                  </div>
                                  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn-info float-right" value="next" />



                              </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-card">
                                    <h2 class="fs-title">Test step7</h2> 

                                    <div class=" form-group">
                                      <label>test: </label>
                                      <input class=" form-control"
                                             name="secondname"
                                             placeholder="" required
                                             type="text">
                                    </div>



                                  </div>
                                  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn-info float-right" value="next" />



                              </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-card">
                                    <h2 class="fs-title">Test step8</h2> 

                                    <div class=" form-group">
                                      <label>test: </label>
                                      <input class=" form-control"
                                             name="secondname"
                                             placeholder="" required
                                             type="text">
                                    </div>



                                  </div>
                                  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn-info float-right" value="next" />



                              </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-card">
                                    <h2 class="fs-title">Test step9</h2> 

                                    <div class=" form-group">
                                      <label>test: </label>
                                      <input class=" form-control"
                                             name="secondname"
                                             placeholder="" required
                                             type="text">
                                    </div>



                                  </div>
                                  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn-info float-right" value="next" />



                              </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-card">
                                    <h2 class="fs-title">Test step10</h2> 

                                    <div class=" form-group">
                                      <label>test: </label>
                                      <input class=" form-control"
                                             name="secondname"
                                             placeholder="" required
                                             type="text">
                                    </div>



                                  </div>
                                  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn-info float-right" value="submit" />



                              </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

html {
    height: 100%
}

#grad1 {

}

#msform {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px
}

#msform fieldset .form-card {
    background: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 20px 40px 30px 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 94%;
    margin: 0 3% 20px 3%;
    position: relative
}

#msform fieldset {
    background: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative
}

#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none
}

#msform fieldset .form-card {
    text-align: left;
    color: #9E9E9E
}

#msform input,
#msform textarea {
    padding: 0px 8px 4px 8px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0.4285rem !important;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 1px
}

#msform input:focus,
#msform textarea:focus {
    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 2px solid skyblue;
    outline-width: 0
}

#msform .action-button {
    width: 100px;
    background: skyblue;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px
}

#msform .action-button:hover,
#msform .action-button:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px skyblue
}

#msform .action-button-previous {
    width: 100px;
    background: #616161;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px
}

#msform .action-button-previous:hover,
#msform .action-button-previous:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #616161
}

select.list-dt {
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 2px 5px 3px 5px;
    margin: 2px
}

select.list-dt:focus {
    border-bottom: 2px solid skyblue
}

.card {
    z-index: 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    position: relative
}

.fs-title {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #2C3E50;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left
}

#progressbar {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: lightgrey,

}

#progressbar .active {
    color: #000000
}

#progressbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 7%;
    float: left;
    position: relative
}

#progressbar #step1:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f023"
}

#progressbar #step1:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f007"
}

#progressbar #step2:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f007"
}

#progressbar #step3:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f007"
}
#progressbar #step4:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f007"
}
#progressbar #step5:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f007"
}
#progressbar #step6:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f007"
}
#progressbar #step7:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f007"
}
#progressbar #step8:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f007"
}

#progressbar #step9:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f09d"
}

#progressbar #step10:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f09d"
}

#progressbar #step11:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f09d"
}

#progressbar #step12:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f09d"
}


#progressbar #step13:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f00c"
}

#progressbar li:before {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 45px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: lightgray;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
    padding: 2px
}

#progressbar li:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: lightgray;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 25px;
    z-index: -1

}

#progressbar li.active:before,
#progressbar li.active:after {
    background: skyblue
}

.radio-group {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 25px
}

.radio {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 204;
    height: 104;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: lightblue;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 8px 2px
}

.radio:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
}

.radio.selected {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
}

.fit-image {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover
}
```

js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
  var opacity;

  $(".next").click(function(){

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

  //Add Class Active
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

  //show the next fieldset
  next_fs.show();
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now) {
  // for making fielset appear animation
  opacity = 1 - now;

  current_fs.css({
  'display': 'none',
  'position': 'relative'
  });
  next_fs.css({'opacity': opacity});
  },
  duration: 600
  });
  });

  $(".previous").click(function(){

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

  //Remove class active
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

  //show the previous fieldset
  previous_fs.show();

  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now) {
  // for making fielset appear animation
  opacity = 1 - now;

  current_fs.css({
  'display': 'none',
  'position': 'relative'
  });
  previous_fs.css({'opacity': opacity});
  },
  duration: 600
  });
  });

  $('.radio-group .radio').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().find('.radio').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  });

  $(".submit").click(function(){
  return false;
  })

  });
```

Comment: you can try to reduce the size of the li elements to fit on the mobile screen and show the lines. Again after can be spoken.

Comment: thank you for the response,  you mean reduce this #progressbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 7%;
    float: left;
    position: relative
}                but how can I add test for this where screen change

Answer (score 0):

I've made the arrangements for you. I mentioned the changes I made in the comment lines. I have some advice I can give you.

1-be more careful when using the Bootstrap grid system, usually bootstrap already offers a responsible structure. when adjusting column sizes, remember that each size will react differently.

2-even if you make some structures responsible, especially in small sizes such as mobile, you may need to change the dimensions with media query to fit the items on the screen.

```css
  * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

html {
  height: 100%
}

#grad1 {}

#msform {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px
}

#msform fieldset .form-card {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 20px 40px 30px 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 94%;
  margin: 0 3% 20px 3%;
  position: relative
}

#msform fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative
}

#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none
}

#msform fieldset .form-card {
  text-align: left;
  color: #9E9E9E
}

#msform input,
#msform textarea {
  padding: 0px 8px 4px 8px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0.4285rem !important;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: montserrat;
  color: #2C3E50;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1px
}

#msform input:focus,
#msform textarea:focus {
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 2px solid skyblue;
  outline-width: 0
}

#msform .action-button {
  width: 100px;
  background: skyblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px
}

#msform .action-button:hover,
#msform .action-button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px skyblue
}

#msform .action-button-previous {
  width: 100px;
  background: #616161;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px
}

#msform .action-button-previous:hover,
#msform .action-button-previous:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #616161
}

select.list-dt {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 2px 5px 3px 5px;
  margin: 2px
}

select.list-dt:focus {
  border-bottom: 2px solid skyblue
}

.card {
  z-index: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  position: relative
}

.fs-title {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #2C3E50;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left
}

#progressbar {
  display: flex;
  /* added*/
  justify-content: center;
  /* added*/
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  /* overflow: hidden; removed */
  color: lightgrey;
}

#progressbar .active {
  color: #000000
}

#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 94%;
  /* changed and calc for form width*/
  position: relative
}

#progressbar #step1:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f023"
}

#progressbar #step1:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f007"
}

#progressbar #step2:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f007"
}

#progressbar #step3:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f007"
}

#progressbar #step4:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f007"
}

#progressbar #step5:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f007"
}

#progressbar #step6:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f007"
}

#progressbar #step7:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f007"
}

#progressbar #step8:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f007"
}

#progressbar #step9:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f09d"
}

#progressbar #step10:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f09d"
}

#progressbar #step11:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f09d"
}

#progressbar #step12:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f09d"
}

#progressbar #step13:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f00c"
}

#progressbar li:before {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 45px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  padding: 2px
}

#progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: lightgray;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 25px;
  z-index: -1
}

#progressbar li.active:before,
#progressbar li.active:after {
  background: skyblue
}

.radio-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 25px
}

.radio {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 204;
  height: 104;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: lightblue;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 8px 2px
}

.radio:hover {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
}

.radio.selected {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
}

.fit-image {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover
}


/*  Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px) */

@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  /* added all this*/
  #progressbar li:before {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 7px;
  }
  #progressbar li:after {
    top: 18px;
    z-index: -1
  }
  /*  Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px) */
  @media (max-width: 767.98px) {}
  /*  Medium devices (tablets, less than 992px) */
  @media (max-width: 991.98px) {}
  /*  Large devices (desktops, less than 1200px) */
  @media (max-width: 1199.98px) {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/dc0c634418.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid" id="grad1">


    <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-center mt-0">

      <div class=" card-header">
        <h2 class="title float-left" style="color:cadetblue;">
          <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Save Request
        </h2>


      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12 text-center p-0 mt-3 mb-2">
        <div class="card px-0 pt-4 pb-0 mt-3 mb-3">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <form id="msform">
                <!-- progressbar -->
                <ul id="progressbar">
                  <li class="active" id="step1"><strong>1</strong></li>
                  <li id="step2"><strong>2</strong></li>
                  <li id="step3"><strong>3</strong></li>
                  <li id="step4"><strong>4</strong></li>
                  <li id="step5"><strong>5</strong></li>
                  <li id="step6"><strong>6</strong></li>
                  <li id="step7"><strong>7</strong></li>
                  <li id="step8"><strong>8</strong></li>
                  <li id="step9"><strong>9</strong></li>
                  <li id="step10"><strong>10</strong></li>

                </ul>
                <!-- fieldsets -->
                <fieldset>
                  <div class="form-card">
                    <h2 class="fs-title">Test step1</h2>

                    <div class=" form-group">
                      <label>test: </label>
                      <input class=" form-control" name="secondname" placeholder="" required type="text">
                    </div>

                    <div>
                      <label>Last NAME: </label>
                      <input name="secondname" placeholder="" required type="text">
                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn-info float-right" value="next" />



                </fieldset>


                <fieldset>
                  <div class="form-card">
                    <h2 class="fs-title">Test step2</h2>

                    <div class=" form-group">
                      <label>Adr: </label>
                      <input class=" form-control" name="secondname" placeholder="" required type="text">
                    </div>

                    <div>
                      <label>Phone: </label>
                      <input name="secondname" placeholder="" required type="text">
                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn-info float-right" value="next" />



                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                  <div class="form-card">
                    <h2 class="fs-title">Test step3</h2>

                    <div class=" form-group">
                      <label>test: </label>
                      <input class=" form-control" name="secondname" placeholder="" required type="text">
                    </div>



                  </div>
                  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn-info float-right" value="next" />



                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                  <div class="form-card">
                    <h2 class="fs-title">Test step4</h2>

                    <div class=" form-group">
                      <label>test: </label>
                      <input class=" form-control" name="secondname" placeholder="" required type="text">
                    </div>



                  </div>
                  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn-info float-right" value="next" />



                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                  <div class="form-card">
                    <h2 class="fs-title">Test step5</h2>

                    <div class=" form-group">
                      <label>test: </label>
                      <input class=" form-control" name="secondname" placeholder="" required type="text">
                    </div>



                  </div>
                  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn-info float-right" value="next" />



                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                  <div class="form-card">
                    <h2 class="fs-title">Test step6</h2>

                    <div class=" form-group">
                      <label>test: </label>
                      <input class=" form-control" name="secondname" placeholder="" required type="text">
                    </div>



                  </div>
                  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn-info float-right" value="next" />



                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                  <div class="form-card">
                    <h2 class="fs-title">Test step7</h2>

                    <div class=" form-group">
                      <label>test: </label>
                      <input class=" form-control" name="secondname" placeholder="" required type="text">
                    </div>



                  </div>
                  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn-info float-right" value="next" />



                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                  <div class="form-card">
                    <h2 class="fs-title">Test step8</h2>

                    <div class=" form-group">
                      <label>test: </label>
                      <input class=" form-control" name="secondname" placeholder="" required type="text">
                    </div>



                  </div>
                  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn-info float-right" value="next" />



                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                  <div class="form-card">
                    <h2 class="fs-title">Test step9</h2>

                    <div class=" form-group">
                      <label>test: </label>
                      <input class=" form-control" name="secondname" placeholder="" required type="text">
                    </div>



                  </div>
                  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn-info float-right" value="next" />



                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                  <div class="form-card">
                    <h2 class="fs-title">Test step10</h2>

                    <div class=" form-group">
                      <label>test: </label>
                      <input class=" form-control" name="secondname" placeholder="" required type="text">
                    </div>



                  </div>
                  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn-info float-right" value="submit" />



                </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```